# Why doesn't IActionFilter.OnActionExecuted get called?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

```
public class FirstActionAttribute : FilterAttribute, IActionFilter
{
    /* Is Called */
    public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {}

    public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {}
}

public class SecondActionAttribute : FilterAttribute, IActionFilter
{
    /* Isn't Called */
    public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {}

    public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
           filterContext.Result = new ViewResult { ViewName = "NotIndex" };
    }
}

    [FirstAction(Order =1)]
    [SecondAction(Order=2)]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

`OnActionExecuted()` is called for action filters whose `OnActionExecuting()` was called before  the action filter that set the `Result` property and as such canceled the execution of an action method. In our case,  `FirstAction.OnActionExecuted` gets called, while `SecondAction.OnActionExecuted` doesn't.

a) What's the purpose of having `FirstAction.OnActionExecuted` called, if *`Index` action method* is never executed?

b) Anyway, since `FirstAction.OnActionExecuted` does get called, why isn't then `SecondAction.OnActionExecuted` also executed?

Comment: @gnat: again, what research are you talking about?! I already did the research, hence how I know that OnActionExecuted doesn't get called for a filter if that filter's OnActionExecuting sets the Result property. Know I'm asking why such a design decision is a good idea